# Unable to install NServiceBus service on server; cryptic error message

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I have been developing some new NServiceBus services, and everything works fine on my development machine (how many stories start that way?). When I zip up the binaries and move them so our server however, I can't install them. In fact, I can't run the host at all. Running the NServiceBus host with *any argument* (except `/?`) results in the following output:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo' from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
    at NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I can't find any information about what's really going on here. Any help shedding light on the subject would be much appreciated, since I've not found anyone on Google talking about this error already.

Comment: Check TypeLoadException properties and InnerException, it contains more useful information about exact error.

Comment: How can I do that? The exception is not being thrown by my application; it's being thrown by the NServiceBus.host.exe. I can't debug that, can I?

Comment: Do you have .NET 4 on the target machine?

Comment: Yes, .NET 4 is installed. I am able to run other .NET applications without issue, including services written for older versions of NServiceBus.

Comment: Are the DLLs blocked?  Since you zipped them and moved them from another machine, the OS may not "trust" the DLLs unless you explicitly unblock them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhh, so it turns out that Adam Fyles was pretty much correct, except that it was .NET 4.5 instead of 4.0.

I've not seen this happen before - but installing 4.5 fixed the issue. Thanks for your help.